# Подскажите, как из этой функции вывести нечетные числа?

Tags: php, рекурсия

```
echo '<h1>Task 6</h1>';

function foo_even($a, $b) {
        if ($a % 2 == 0 && $a < $b) {
            echo $a . '<br/>';
            foo_even($a+2,$b);
        }
}

foo_even(10,35);
```

Comment: Это какая-то очень извращенная функция, которая находит все четные числа от 10 до 35?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function foo_odd($a, $b)
{
    // Если достигли ограничителя - пришла пора выйти из рекурсии
    if ($a >= $b)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Проверяем, что число нечетное
    if ($a % 2 != 0)
    {
        echo $a . '<br/>';

        // Этот код не будет работать
        // Если изначально вызвать функцию с четным первым аргументом, рекурсия никогда не начнется
        // foo_odd($a + 2, $b);
    }

    // Рекурсивно вызываем функцию, увеличивая число
    foo_odd($a + 1, $b);
}

foo_odd(10, 35);
```

Собственно, и оригинальная функция тоже работать не будет, если вызвать ее первый раз с нечетным числом. Это легко исправить, если взять мой вариант за основу.

Разумеется, без рекурсии функция еще проще:

```
function foo_odd($a, $b)
{
    for ($i = $a; $i < $b; $i++)
    {
        if ($i % 2 != 0)
        {
            echo $i.'<br/>';
        }
    }
}

foo_odd(11, 35);
```

Comment: Спасибо! исчерпывающий ответ